# ggplot2, multiple lines plot(from grammar point of view)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 codes:

The first code makes plot with one lm line:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = class)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

The second codemakes plot with `n` lm lines:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy,colour = class)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

from the `grammar` point of view, can you please explain how the `colour = class`(or more precisely the place in code line, where this input is situated) influences on the plot(one line or multiple lines)?

Many thanks.

Comment: aesthetic inheritance. All layers inherit from the aes parameters passed to ggplot so `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()` == `ggplot(mpg,aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point(aes(colour=class)) + geom_smooth(aes(colour=class))`

Comment: First of all, your first line of code is wrong and produces an error so remove ``colour=class`` from the ``geom_point()`` call. Second, the reason adding ``colour=class`` to aesthetics creates "n lm lines" is because you'r mapping a factor variable with a specified number of levels into the color aesthetics, thus it creates the same number of lm lines as you have classes.

Comment: First line needs to be: `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point(aes(colour=class)) + geom_smooth(se = FALSE)`